# How to control emulator in intelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to switch in intelliJ idea from eclipse but I can't find some tools like eclipse. one of them is  DDMS explorer which is used to control emulator. Can anybody help me to adjust in intelliJ idea?

Answer (score 2):

The DDMS explorer is not integrated in IntelliJ, but you are able to launch the DDMS tools from the menu. 
Tools -> Android -> DDMS

For more information, check out [this blogpost](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/launching-android-tools-right-from-intellij-idea/).